# Images "glitched" in iOS 8 displayed differently to 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage, ios8

I have a small app that lets you glitch an image (along the lines of: http://snorpey.github.io/jpg-glitch/ etc) though the way the images are handled in iOS 8 (and the new accompanying XCode6-Beta2) seems different and the glitched images no longer display nicely.

Original:
[image: Original]

iOS7:
[image: iOS7]

iOS8:
[image: iOS8]

To make sure it wasn't something strange in my project I made a slimmed down version with just the glitch code and it still didn't work, you can see the code here: [github.com/n1c/GlitchTest/](https://github.com/n1c/GlitchTest/)

Comment: While iOS 8 is still in the beta, I would not rush things.. There could be some things yet to be fixed in iOS 8 from Apple side.. The same was with the iOS 7.  If You can - wait and see if problem remains after the next releases of iOS 8.

Comment: TBH I prefer the iOS 8 render.